# C# entityframework 6 how to save children after modifying the children state

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I am trying out a simple save with entityframework context. I have an entity 'User' and children property 'Subordinates'

I want to loop through Subordinates, make some changes and save the context. Currently it is not saving with my code. Can anyone help me with this?

```
[Table("org.User")]
public partial class User
{
    public string PersonNumber { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// User Manager
    /// </summary>
    public virtual User User2 { get; set; }

    public string ManagerEmployeeNo { get; set; }   
}

public class SapService
{
        using (var context = new Data.OrganisationContext())
    {
        var usr = (from user in context.Users
                where user.ID == userId
                select user).FirstOrDefault();

        context.Users.Add(usr);

        UpdateSubOrdinatesManagerReference(context, usr);
context.SaveChanges()
    }

        private void UpdateSubOrdinatesManagerReference(Data.OrganisationContext orgContext, Data.User user)
        {
            var subordinates = orgContext.Users
                .Where(subordinate => subordinate.ManagerEmployeeNo == user.PersonNumber && !subordinate.Disabled);

            foreach (var subordinate in subordinates)
                subordinate.User2 = user;
        }
}
```

Comment: Are your entities "database-first?"  Have they been generated by Entity Framework?

Comment: My entities are database-first

Comment: OK.  I guess you'd better show us a bit more code, including the relevant entity classes.

Comment: @RobertHarvey i have updated with my entity classes

Comment: Is `ManagerEmployeeNo` defined as the foreign-key property for the `User2` navigation property? If it is, you're essentially not making any changes to the subordinates.

Comment: No, ManagerEmployeeNo is not defined as foreign-key property. But the context is configured as
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasMany(e => e.User1)
                .WithOptional(e => e.User2)
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.ManagerID);

Comment: @RobertHarvey in my code, i am passing the context to a method. is that right way?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "right."  Seems like it should work.